# how do i use vlookup using python having mutliple columns in both dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, left-join, vlookup

I need help on vlookup using python. I need only one matching column data of df2 in df1 instead of all
df2 data.
my input is below two dataframes.

```
df1 
NodeName    NEID    Configured_Speed
MUM         25234   511.054
DEL         32251   154.155
CHN         32584   224.949
KOL         27076   372.932
PUN         29743   203.556
TN          29037   224.949
```

```
df2 

NodeName    Address         Region
KOL         10.134.9.242    East
DEL         10.51.195.236   North
CHN         10.139.56.59    South
TN          10.133.19.251   South
KEL         10.51.60.6      South
MUM         10.1.59.193     West
PUN         10.51.60.66     West
```

and my Output is

```
NodeName    NEID    Configured_Speed    Address
MUM         25234   511.054             10.1.59.193
DEL         32251   154.155             10.51.195.236
CHN         32584   224.949             10.139.56.59
KOL         27076   372.932             10.134.9.242
PUN         29743   203.556             10.51.60.66
TN          29037   224.949             10.133.19.251
```

I tried below code but getting Address column blank.

```
df1['Address']=df1.NodeName.map(df2.Address)
```

and when i use below code, all columns from `df2` came in `df1`

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='NodeName',how ='left')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset `df2` to send only the desired columns for the merging process-

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['NodeName', 'Address']], on ='NodeName', how ='left')
```

Comment: Thanks al lot. but i want Output data-frame is df1 with updated Address column, because there are multiple columns (more than 30) columns in df1 and i have to do more calculation in df1. Also plz help how u have edited question so can do it further.

Comment: Hi @SudarshanWaman , do you mind clarifying your question?

Comment: Thanks@IsseyChua.  Actually my df1 have more than 30 columns and i have given only 3 columns which are required. and i have to do many calculation on df1 after this vlookup with df2. so my question is :- Is there any possibility to do the same vlookup in df1 only. Like df1['Address'] = pd.merge(df1, df2[['NodeName', 'Address']], on ='NodeName',how ='left').

Comment: Did it not answer your original question? Your follow-up question is not clear, do you want  something like this- df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['NodeName', 'Address']], on ='NodeName', how ='left')

Comment: @SudarshanWaman glad to know

Comment: @meVerma. the count of rows of df3 are not equal to rows count of df1 .which should be same. could you please help on this. this is happening with me when i am using same for big data. my df1 rows are 63000 and df2 95000 and getting df3 rows value  is 79050. but which should be exact 63000.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2['NodeName','Address'],on='NodeName',how='left')
```

Comment: This is incorrect as you're merging df1 with only an Address col of df2 on col NodeName, which will throw a KeyError as there is no col named NodeName in your second dataframe, i.e., df2['Address']

Comment: Thank you @mrVerma, I changed to code accordingly.